# Bidirectional entity relationship saves id null using Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning about Spring boot with JpaRepository and I'm stagnant with this problem.
I'm triying to save a list of objects but they save with id null of all objects in the bidirectional relationship, I saw a lot of examples and all it worked ok, even I have another project with the same example but different entities and that works fine, I hope I have expressed myself correctly with my problem

**A class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="producto")
public class Producto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    // there are more attributes but i'm hiding It to show less code to  try this more easier to see

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="proveedor_id")
    private Proveedor proveedor;

// getters and setter

// constructor empty and others constructors
```

**another class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="proveedores")
public class Proveedor {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name="id")
   private Long id;


   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proveedor", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Producto> listaProducto =  new ArrayList<Producto>();

// getters and setter

// constructor empty and others constructors
```

**this is the test**

```
   @Test
   void addProveedorConProductos() {
   Proveedor test = new Proveedor();
   List<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<Producto>();
       lista.add(new Producto("bbb","pruebaTest2",123,null,null,null));
       lista.add(new Producto("a","pruebaTest21111",123,null,null,null));
       test = new Proveedor("pruebaTestCase", 12345,lista);
       assertNotNull(proveedor.save(test));

   }
```

**The result**

All save ok but the id_proveedor saves null, this is an image of the result https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FQYp.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already implemented project the same your situation. You can refer my code, hope you have more idea to solve your problem.

First step: Create role entity have many-many relationship with user entity

```
package com.tvp.springrest.role;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.tvp.springrest.user.User;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ERole name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private List<User> users;

public Role(ERole name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Role() {
}

}
```

Create Enum Role:

```
package com.tvp.springrest.role;

public enum ERole {
USER("USER"),
MODERATOR("MODERATOR"),
ADMIN("ADMIN");

private String value;

ERole(String value){
    this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public static ERole fromString(String roleString){
    for(ERole role: ERole.values()){
        if(role.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(roleString)){
            return role;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Second step: Create User entity

```
package com.tvp.springrest.user;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.tvp.springrest.role.Role;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "users",
uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =  "email")
}
)
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 20)
private String username;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 50)
@Email
private String email;

@NotBlank
@Size(max = 120)
private String password;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",
    joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

public User(@NotBlank @Size(max = 20) String username, @NotBlank @Size(max = 50) @Email String email,
        @NotBlank @Size(max = 120) String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}

public User() {
}

public User(@NotBlank @Size(max = 20) String username, @NotBlank @Size(max = 50) @Email String email,
        @NotBlank @Size(max = 120) String password, Set<Role> roles) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.roles = roles;
}

}
```

Third step: You need create Repository for role and user entity

```
package com.tvp.springrest.role;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {
  Optional<Role> findByName(ERole name);
}
```

For User

```
package com.tvp.springrest.user;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

Boolean existsByUsername(String username);

Boolean existsByEmail(String name);

}
```

After that you can create data for database:

```
package com.tvp.springrest;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import com.tvp.springrest.employee.EmployeeRepository;
import com.tvp.springrest.order.OrderRepository;
import com.tvp.springrest.role.ERole;
import com.tvp.springrest.role.Role;
import com.tvp.springrest.role.RoleRepository;
import com.tvp.springrest.user.User;
import com.tvp.springrest.user.UserRepository;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Configuration
public class LoadDatabase {

@Bean
CommandLineRunner initDatabase(
  RoleRepository roleRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
return args -> {

  roleRepository.save(new Role(ERole.ADMIN));
  roleRepository.save(new Role(ERole.MODERATOR));
  roleRepository.save(new Role(ERole.USER));

  Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
  roles.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.ADMIN).get());
  roles.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.MODERATOR).get());
  roles.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.USER).get());

  Set<Role> roles1 = new HashSet<>();
  roles1.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.USER).get());

  Set<Role> roles2 = new HashSet<>();
  roles2.add(roleRepository.findByName(ERole.MODERATOR).get());

  userRepository.save(new User("test1", "test1@gmail.com", "123456", roles));
  userRepository.save(new User("test2", "test2@gmail.com", "123456", roles1));
  userRepository.save(new User("test3", "test3@gmail.com", "123456", roles2));

};
}

}
```

Comment: I have fixed it, thanks so much for the time that you wasted trying to help me

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to save Producto before.
And after that, you call find on Producto in database, and you can add Producto to Proveedor. Hope you can solve this problem.
Like that:

```
productoRepository.save(new Producto("bbb","pruebaTest2",123,null,null,null));
productoRepository.save(new Producto("a","pruebaTest21111",123,null,null,null)));
List<Producto> lista = productoRepository.findAll();
proveedorRepository.save(new Proveedor("pruebaTestCase", 12345, lista);
```